# How to make a 'sign-up for newsletter'?

Tags: web-development, website-design, website-features, personal-website

Can anyone please help on how to make a sign-up for newsletter for for a website using Html and Css

Comment: There are many ways to make a sign-up for a newsletter using HTML and CSS.   Please ask something more specific about it.

Answer (score 1):

Created this simple one using HTML and Bootstrap CSS. Hope it helps.

```
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                     Signup
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading text-success">
                            Any text
                        </h4>
                        <p class="margin-top-10 margin-bottom-20">
                            Any text.
                        </p>
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="newsletter-name" class="hidden">Name</label>
                                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="newsletter-name" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="newsletter-email" class="hidden">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="newsletter-email" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-success">Signup</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">  for stylesheet.